# How to make an exe with Launch4j that does not require admin priviledges with a bundled JRE?

Tags: java, launch4j

I'm attempting to create an installer for my Java application, and am using IzPack with launch4j and a bundled JRE to do so. I have it working so that the installer gets generated, and an executable created from the installer. When I try to execute the installer in Windows 7, I'm prompted to run as admin. I want to generate the installer so that the user doesn't have to run it with elevated privileges, and install the application to their home directory.

Is this even possible? What changes do I need to make to get it to work?
Here's my maven configuration for Launch4J:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>launch4j-gui</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>launch4j</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
                <headerType>gui</headerType>
                <jar>${project.build.directory}/${installer-output-jar}</jar>
                <outfile>${project.build.directory}/${installer-output-exe}</outfile>
                <errTitle></errTitle>
                <cmdLine></cmdLine>
                <chdir>.</chdir>
                <priority>normal</priority>
                <downloadUrl></downloadUrl>
                <supportUrl></supportUrl>
                <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
                <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
                <manifest></manifest>
                <icon></icon>
                <jre>
                    <path>jre1.8.0_112</path>
                    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
                    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
                    <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
                    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
                    <jdkPreference>jdkOnly</jdkPreference>
                    <runtimeBits>64</runtimeBits>
                </jre>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi Robert, Did you find any way for this? I have same requirement.

Comment: I didn't figure this out, sorry.

Comment: Still didn’t find out?

Comment: Sadly, nope, I don't think there's an answer here.